# Convert datetime from plsql to redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
select last_day(add_months(last_day(trunc(to_date('20230509', 'yyyymmdd'))), - 1)) + 1.25 
from dual;
```

Results in: 2023-05-01 06:00:00

I want to convert the above SQL to redshift runnable but failed

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD('day', 1.25, LAST_DAY(DATEADD('month', -1, TRUNC(TO_DATE('20230509', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'MM')))) AS new_date;
```

> ERROR: function trunc(date, "unknown") does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts. [ErrorId: 1-6459c3b1-5d1417c704fa148d1a360f70]

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because the function trunc(timestamp) has only one argument.  I think you are looking for date_trunc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html

This will give you a timestamp which you can cast or trunc() if you need.

Or you could just force the day portion of you input string to 01.